# Yet some other integrals containing an inverse trigonometric and a rational function.

Tags: definite-integrals, cauchy-integral-formula, polylogarithm

Let $a,b\in(0,1)$.

In the course of solving [Evaluating a double integral of a complicated rational function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075145/evaluating-a-double-integral-of-a-complicated-rational-function/2762098#2762098) we came across the following definite integrals:
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak J}_1(a,b) &:=& \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\arctan(\frac{b}{x})}{(x+a/2)^2+(1-b)^2/4} dx\\
{\mathfrak J}_2(a,b) &:=& \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\arctan(\frac{1}{x+a})}{(x+a/2)^2+(1-b)^2/4} dx
\end{eqnarray}

Since $\arctan(x)=\imath/2(\log(1-\imath x)-\log(1+\imath x))$ and since the inverse of the denominator can always be decomposed into partial fractions the anti-derivatives of both integrands above can be found and are expressed through logs and di-logarithms only. Then the values of those anti-derivatives at positive and negative infinities can be taken and the integrals above evaluated. We have therefore carried out those calculations and obtained the following results:
\begin{equation}
{\mathfrak J}_1(a,b)=-\frac{2 \pi}{1-b} \arctan(\frac{2 a b}{1+a^2-b^2})
\end{equation}
The second integral is more complicated since, as it turns out, the anti-derivative has two discontinuity points in the real axis at $x\in \left\{-a,-a b/(1+b)\right\}$. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&{\mathfrak J}_2(a,b)=\frac{1}{2(1-b)} \sum\limits_{\xi=\pm} \sum\limits_{\eta=\pm} \xi \eta\\
&& \left( \right.\\
&&\left.
(g_+^{(\eta,\xi)}-g^{(\eta,\xi)}(-\frac{a b}{1-b}+\epsilon))+\right.\\
&&\left.
(g^{(\eta,\xi)}(-\frac{a b}{1-b}-\epsilon)-g^{(\eta,\xi)}(-a+\epsilon))+\right.\\
&&\left.
(g^{(\eta,\xi)}(-a-\epsilon)-g_-^{(\eta,\xi)}\right.)\\
&&\left.
\right)
\end{eqnarray}

where
\begin{eqnarray}
&&g^{(\eta,\xi)}(x):= \frac{1}{2} \log ^2\left(-\frac{2 (a+x)}{a+i b \eta -i \eta }\right)-\frac{1}{2} \log ^2\left(-\frac{2 (a+x+i \xi )}{2 (a+i \xi )-a+i b \eta -i \eta }\right)+\\
&&\log (a+x+i \xi ) \log \left(1-\frac{2 (a+x+i \xi )}{2 (a+i \xi )-a+i b \eta -i \eta }\right)-\log (a+x) \log \left(1-\frac{2 (a+x)}{a+i b \eta -i \eta }\right)+\\
&&\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a+i b \eta -i \eta }{2 (a+x)}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{-a+i b \eta -i \eta +2 (a+i \xi )}{2 (a+x+i \xi )}\right)+\\
&&2\pi \imath 1_{\xi=-1} 1_{x\le -a} \log(a-\imath (-1+b) \eta +2 x)
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
&&g_+^{(\eta,\xi)} = \frac{1}{2} \left( 
\log(\frac{-2}{a+\imath(-1+b)\eta})^2 - \log(\frac{-2}{a+\imath((-1+b)\eta+2\xi)})^2\right)\\
&&g_-^{(\eta,\xi)} =
\frac{1}{2} (-\log (a-i (1-b) \eta )-\log (a-i (-b \eta +\eta +2))+2 \log (2))\cdot \\
&& (\log (a-i (-b \eta +\eta +2))-\log (a-i (1-b) \eta ))+\\
&&\left\{ \begin{array}{r} i \pi  (\log (a-i (1-b) \eta )-\log (a+i (b \eta -\eta +2))) & \mbox{if $\xi=1$} \\ -2 \pi ^2 \eta +i \pi  (\log (a-i (1-b \eta ))+\log (a-i (-b \eta +2 \eta +1))) & \mbox{if $\xi=-1$} \end{array} \right.
\end{eqnarray}
Now we expand the complex quantities and simplify the result and again we get neat closed form results. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum\limits_{\xi=\pm} \sum\limits_{\eta=\pm} \eta \xi(g^{(\eta,\xi)}_+-g^{(\eta,\xi)}_-) &=& -4 \pi\left(\pi+\arctan(\frac{2 a(-1+b)}{a^2-(-3+b)(1+b)})\right) \\
\sum\limits_{\xi=\pm} \sum\limits_{\eta=\pm} \eta \xi(
g^{(\eta,\xi)}(-\frac{a b}{1+b}-\epsilon)-g^{(\eta,\xi)}(-\frac{a b}{1+b}+\epsilon)) &=& 4\pi \arctan(\frac{1+b}{a})\\
\sum\limits_{\xi=\pm} \sum\limits_{\eta=\pm} \eta \xi(
g^{(\eta,\xi)}(-a-\epsilon)-g^{(\eta,\xi)}(-a+\epsilon)) &=&
4 \pi\left(\pi - \arctan(\frac{1-b}{a}) \right)
\end{eqnarray}
Putting everything together we have:
\begin{equation}
{\mathfrak J}_2(a,b)= \frac{2 \pi}{(1-b)} \arctan\left( \frac{2 a}{3+a^2-4 b+b^2}\right)
\end{equation}
Now, the obvious question would be is it possible to derive those results using some other method, for example using complex analysis.